# UIImagePickerViewController dismiss slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some code which runs when UIImagePickerViewController picks an image, but despite `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` being the first line, it waits until all the code is complete before it dismisses. How can i stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about -

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
    // stuff I want to do...
}];
```

Comment: TIL. Not sure how i never knew about that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this hasn't been working. It's not calling the completion argument.

Comment: Must be another problem then, as this is the Apple recommended way of doing it now (your method is deprecated)